# Magento 2.2.4 : Customer nav account

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, navigation

I have created some links that i have added to my customer account nav.

But there's some problem :

1. My links aren't order one under each other
2. The class current is only active on "Mon cadencier" link.

Here's customer_account.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-contacts">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mycontacts/contacts/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes contacts</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-factures">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mybills/factures/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes factures</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</argument>

                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-reclamations">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mycomplaints/reclamations/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes réclamations</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-cadencier">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customercadencier/order/cadencier</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mon cadencier</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>


        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
        <!--<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>-->
        <!--<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" remove="true"/>-->
        <!--<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>-->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />


    </body>
</page>
```

See the result :

[image: result]

Comment: Have you tried our solution ? Is this work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">

            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-contacts">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mycontacts/contacts/index</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes contacts</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-factures">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mybills/factures/index</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes factures</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</argument>

                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-reclamations">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mycomplaints/reclamations/index</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mes réclamations</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-cadencier">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customercadencier/order/cadencier</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Mon cadencier</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
            <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
            </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope it will works.